# recursive JSON decode on php

Tags: php, json, recursion, escaping, double-quotes

I have a data save on sql, and when I import it to php and try to decode into a object, I am finding a little problem because there are many objects inside the main object. The data I have is this:

```
[{
    "other":"{
        \"father\":\"[\"father-3\",\"undefined\",\"father-class\"]\",
        \"element\":\"[\"element-3\",\"height: 265px;\",\"element-class\"]\"
    }",
    "type":"login",
    "columns":4,
    "offsets":0,
    "order":"father,facebook,twitter,email",
    "father":"{login-title}"
},
{
    "other":"{
        \"text\":\"[\"text-4\",\"\",\"text-class\"]\",
        \"element\":\"[\"element-4\",\"height: 265px;\",\"element-class\"]\"
    }",
    "type":"text",
    "columns":4,
    "offsets":2,
    "order":"text",
    "text":"<p>hola <strong>muchachos </strong>como est&aacute;is?</p>"
}]
```

"Other" is and object inside each object of this array. When I make a json_decode for the array, I get the array without problems, but if I try to get the other object I get NULL. Finally I found a solution, but I am not sure if it is the best (and this is the reason of my question):

```
$elements = json_decode($value);
foreach($elements as $element)
{
    echo "<h1>ELEMENTO</h1>";
    var_dump($element);
    echo "<h1>ORIGINAL OTHER</h1>";
    echo "<textarea>".$element->other."</textarea>";
    $element->other = str_replace("\"]", "\\\"]",$element->other);
    $element->other = str_replace("[\"", "[\\\"",$element->other);
    $element->other = str_replace("\",\"", "\\\",\\\"",$element->other);
    $element->other = str_replace("]\\\",\\\"", "]\",\"",$element->other);
    $other = json_decode($element->other);
    echo "<h1>OTHER</h1>";
    echo "<textarea>".$element->other."</textarea>";
    var_dump($other);
}
```

$value is the original data from the data base.
The problem I think is happen is that in the ORIGINAL OTHER the text shown hasn´t the scape backslash for the double quotes -> \", instead what I see is:

```
{
    "father":"["father-3","undefined","father-class"]",
    "element":"["element-3","height: 265px;","element-class"]"
}
```

And for this reason I need to make all of this str_replace that I am not loving, and I think that must to be another way to do it.
I am watching that there is a *$depth* limit to decode function, I thought it was for decoding recursive objetcs, but I am not sure how it works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove the double quote when opening and closing the braces and bracket of nested object/array like this

```
"other":{
    \"father\":[\"father-3\",\"undefined\",\"father-class\"],
    \"element\":[\"element-3\",\"height: 265px;\",\"element-class\"]
},
```

and it should decode fine, hope it helps

Comment: I´ll try and feed you back. Thanks @BoH

Comment: Hey. I wonder how you write json data to your database. Can you show your code? Becasue it's strange that you have so many escape chars in your output json. May be you need to change the way how you save your json data.